# How to read all keys and values from a shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am doing a simple application where a ListView is populated from the data stored in SharedPreferences. I need to read all the key pair values from SharedPreference. I used the code given in another post with same question, but it has not helped me at all.
The code is using a Map to getALL() from SharedPreference. When I try to print the count() of keys in the MAP it is always giving zero count. I am stuck in my application building due to this problem.
Can somebody help me with a simple code to retrieve all the key and values from a SharedPreference? Thanks.

Comment: WHat is the code which you tryied. add here

Answer (score 0):

You can store and retrive arraylist or array data like this [Example](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/02/store-arraylist-in-android.html).

You are fetching data into list but you are not storing data into sharedprefence from arraylist.

In this situation(never tried but this may work)

**Store**

1. retrive size variable as in above example
2. increament size by 1(to store one value)
3. store value in SharedPreference
4. Store size in SharedPreference.

**Fetch**

1. retrive size variable as in above example
2. then go through loop for all values